# Create a new line when user presses "Enter" key (HTML & Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome Extension such that the user can create a todo list.  I want to make it so that once a user types out a task, the user can press the "Enter" key to submit it.  This will cause the task to go down to the next line.  I'm having trouble allowing the user to make the task go onto the next line.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="newtask" value="" spellcheck="false" placeholder="New Task" id="newtask">
<ul id="tasksUL">
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(() => {
   $('#newtask').on('keydown', (e) => {
     if(e.keyCode == 13){
       ???
     }
   });
 });
```

Comment: Sorry, your post is a little confusing. What's currently happening when the user presses Enter, and what do you want to happen?

Comment: Add new `li` element to your  list with the entered input value and set input value to empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach `keypress` eventlistener to `input` element, not to `ul`. If the key pressed is enter, get the content of input element, create new `li` element and set it's text with the inputted value, append to `ul` and then clear the `input` element.

```js
$(() => {
  $('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      const newTask = $(this).val();
      if (newTask) {
        $('#tasksUL').append(`<li>${newTask}</li>`);
        $(this).val("");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="newtask" value="" spellcheck="false" placeholder="New Task" id="newtask">
<ul id="tasksUL">
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

With vanilla javascript you just add an `eventListener` to the actual input element
listening for `keydown` events.

```
let tasks = document.getElementById('tasksUL');
document.getElementById('newtask').addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if(e.key == 'Enter'){
        let new_item = document.createElement('li');
        new_item.innerText = e.target.value;
        tasks.appendChild(new_item);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your *list* to contain the text entered by user? You can use the jQuery *append* method to achieve that.

```
$('#newtask').keydown(function(e){
    if (e.which == 13) {
        //Construct some html to append:
        var newLi = "&lt;li&gt;" + $('#newtask').val() + "&lt;/li&gt;";
        $('#tasksUL').append(newLi);
    }
});
```

Try my [JS Fiddle implementation](https://jsfiddle.net/Randy3141/vf3uhnpL/1/)